# add local opencv to path

Tags: ros, opencv, cuda, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to compile my ROS node with the opencv which is at /usr/local/ I have tried the following [rosanswers](http://answers.ros.org/question/242376/having-trouble-using-cuda-enabled-opencv-with-kinetic/?comment=263978#post-id-263978)
I could compile my code without errors. But when i run the node, i get the following error.

```
undefined reference to `cv::cuda::createStereoBM(int, int)'
```

I checked my CMakeCache.txt to see the path for the opencv directories and I get this

```
/usr/local/share/OpenCV
```

The libraries for cudastereo.hpp are in /usr/local/include and not in /usr/local/share.
How do I get my CMakeLists.txt to get the correct OpenCV as I am able to run the code outside ROS with no errors. My CMakeLists.txt is as follows

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
NO_MODULE
PATHS /usr/local
NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(flir_node src/flir_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(flir_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264140/add-local-opencv-to-path/) by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is solved by mentioning the library location and the path separately in the CMakeLists.txt

```
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/)

set(OpenCV_LIBS /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so)
```

This fixed the problem on most cases.

If catkin fails to compile with the local openCV after setting the CMakeLists.txt as above, open the  CMakeCache.txt after it compiles and change the opencv path  in that and recompile. Works!

---

Originally posted by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) with karma: 70 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0